# SQL-How to use ORDER BY to arrange rows in accordance with text instead of numbers

Tags: sql-server

I have been struggling to understand how to arrange rows in a table in order based on a column containing a text instead of numerical data.  Here is the input of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE grocery_price (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, price FLOAT);

INSERT INTO grocery_price VALUES(1, 'Bananas', 1.50);
INSERT INTO grocery_price VALUES(2, 'Peanut Butter', 1.00);
INSERT INTO grocery_price VALUES(3, 'Dark Chocolate Bars', 1.50);
INSERT INTO grocery_price VALUES(4, 'Ice cream', 2.50);
INSERT INTO grocery_price VALUES(5, 'Cherries', 0.50);
INSERT INTO grocery_price VALUES(6, 'Chocolate syrup', 1.25);

SELECT * FROM Grocery;
```

Everything appears fine and anytime that I want to use ORDER BY with a column of integers or floats, it works like I expected it.  However, when I tried to use ORDER BY with the 'name' column, like below:

```
SELECT * FROM Grocery ORDER BY name;
```

This is the result:

> The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

I do not seem to understand why I cannot perform this action with text columns when I can do it fine with integers or floats.  Do I need to convert the text into something else?  If so, how would I convert it?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Don't store `name` as `text`.  As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql) warns:

> IMPORTANT! ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a
>   future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new
>   development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use
>   them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

Change the type to `varchar()` (or `nvarchar()`):

```
CREATE TABLE grocery_price (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(255),
    price FLOAT
);
```

While you are fixing types, I would suggest:

```
CREATE TABLE grocery_price (
    id INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(255),  -- I doubt varchar(max) is needed
    price numeric(10, 2)
);
```

And then save the values as:

```
INSERT INTO grocery_price VALUES('Bananas', 1.50);
INSERT INTO grocery_price VALUES('Peanut Butter', 1.00);
INSERT INTO grocery_price VALUES('Dark Chocolate Bars', 1.50);
INSERT INTO grocery_price VALUES('Ice cream', 2.50);
INSERT INTO grocery_price VALUES('Cherries', 0.50);
INSERT INTO grocery_price VALUES('Chocolate syrup', 1.25);
```

The `id` will be generated automatically.  And the price should be a fixed-point representation rather than a floating point (if you don't understand the difference, you can Google "fixed versus float").

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in error message `text` data type cannot be *sorted*

You have to `cast` the name to `varchar` in `Order by`

```
SELECT * 
FROM grocery_price 
order by cast(name as  varchar(max))
```

**Note :** `Text` will be removed in future versions., start using `varchar` instead

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the data type to varchar and make the field not nullable. It will work.